# Group by a pair

Tags: mysql

My Query

```
SELECT si1.itemno,si2.itemno,count(*) 
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM `saleitems` WHERE orgno = 9) as si1 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM saleitems WHERE orgno =9) as si2 
ON si1.invoiceno = si2.invoiceno AND si1.itemno != si2.itemno WHERE 1 GROUP BY si1.itemno,si2.itemno
```

Output:[click to see output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW8eP.png)

But i expect 'group by (si1.itemno,si2.itemno) pair'. Like 3,4 and 4,3 should be grouped together in a single row.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions. Also explain what you are trying to select from the `saleitems` table. There might be an easier query to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The DBMS doesn't know that `si1.itemno` and `si2.itemno` are interchangeable, so as far as it's concerned `si1.itemno=3,si2.itemno=4` is different from `si1.itemno=4,si2.itemno=3`.

The easiest way to eliminate those duplicates is to change the condition of your self-join so that it only finds the pairs with the IDs in order: just change the `si1.itemno != si2.itemno` condition to `si1.itemno < si2.itemno`.

Note that I referred to it as a "self-join", because although you currently have sub-queries, you don't need to, because you can just move the `WHERE` clauses to the final `WHERE`:

```sql
SELECT
    si1.itemno,
    si2.itemno,
    count(*) 
FROM 
    saleitems as si1 
INNER JOIN 
    saleitems as si2 
    ON si1.invoiceno = si2.invoiceno
    AND si1.itemno < si2.itemno
WHERE
    si1.orgno = 9
    AND si2.orgno = 9
GROUP BY
    si1.itemno,
    si2.itemno
```